# Android new SlidingPaneLayout disable swipe

Tags: android, android-support-library, slidingmenu

I am currently using the new SlidingPaneLayout with a map. The problem is when I interact with the map I always open the left menu. I have already tried to override on touch method on the sliding pane but it did not work. The map is a fragment inside the sliding pane.

Anyone knows how to disable the swipe as a form of opening the side menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this problem changing from SlidingPaneLayout to DrawerLayout.